Definition of minimum of sets of real numbers
I have a question about the definition of "minimum" in a subset of the real numbers. I have found several definitions, but I can't find one that convinces me. Could the following be a definition?
"Let $A$ a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which has a lower bound and $\inf A \in A$; then we can define $\min A := \inf A$."
Is that correct?

That works just fine, but I do wonder what you think is wrong with the usual definition(s).

That works, but seems a bit indirect and somewhat circular.  If it exists, the minimum of a set of real numbers $A$ is the least element in the set.  Thus, if the minimum is $m\in A$ we have $m≤a$ for every $a\in A$.

The point is that the inf is a more subtle concept.  Doesn't exist for the rationals, say.  Why define a more general notion in terms of one more specific?  More importantly:  To define inf, you need the notion of maximum, anyway...so I'd say your definition was at least somewhat circular.

The definition that I searched is for subsets of real numbers, and I didn't find a "rigorous" definition. That's why my question.

@lulu I dont' buy that $\inf$ is more subtle. For one, $\inf$ always exists (if you allow $-\infty$ as a value, anyhow) and $\min$ exists iff $\inf$ lies in the set. Also, $\inf$ does exist for the rationals, just not for arbitrary subsets (much like $\min$ doesn't even in the reals). Also, you can define $\inf$ without recourse to $\max$.

@BenSteffan  How do you define inf without referring to the max?  I have to imagine that any definition one uses can be made into a definition of min simply by adding the condition that the element in question belongs to the given set.

@lulu For instance, given a set $A$ it's the unique $r \in \mathbb{R}$ (or $-\infty$, if no such $r$ exists) such that $(r - \epsilon, r + \epsilon) \cap A = [r, r + \epsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

@BenSteffan  Fair enough.  Though of course you make that into a definition of the min if you preface it with "the unique $r\in A$" instead of "the unique $r\in \mathbb R$".   It just seems to me that min is a more basic concept than inf, so I wouldn't define the former in terms of the latter

@lulu You could, and then the definitions would be about the same. I don't think one is necessarily justified in saying one is more basic than the other, given that you can use one to define the other without much hassle ($\inf$ is $\min$ of closure, $\min$ is $\inf$ that's contained in set), and you can define both without recourse to the other as well.

@BenSteffan  Ok, that's fair.

The minimum of a set $A\subset R$ is the least element in $A$, if that exists.  Thus the minimum is $m$ if $m\in A$ and $a\in A\implies m≤a$.
Defining it in terms of inf may be circular, depending on which definition of $\inf(A)$ is used.  Some of the standard definitions use the notion of maximum.  That is, the inf of $A$ is defined the maximum of all real numbers which are less than or equal to every element in $A$. And if you have a notion of maximum, you have a notion of minimum (if nothing else, you can get $\min(A)$ as $-\max(-A)$.
As remarked by @BenSteffan in the comments, it is possible to define inf without referencing the max, hence it is possible to make the OP's definition of min non-circular.  So, assuming that the OP had such a definition in mind, it works.
The definition proposed by that user was "The unique $r\in\mathbb R$, if it exists,  such that $$(r-\epsilon, r+\epsilon)\cap A=[r, r+\epsilon)\cap A\neq \emptyset,\quad\forall \epsilon>0$$
In parallel fashion, one could define minimum directly by replacing $r\in \mathbb R$ with $r\in  A$ in that definition.
